# Paper accepted with no report?

Tags: publications, mathematics, peer-review

I submitted a 60-page paper to a reasonable math journal (*Journal of Algebra*) about 6 months ago. A few days ago I received an email stating that my paper was accepted. I did not get a referee report. I did not get any comments on my paper.
 Just an acceptance notice.

Is this usual? it seems very strange to me that the referee has absolutely no comment on a 60-page paper!

Should I ask the editor what happened?

Comment: Yes, do ask, but you may have been very thorough and submitted a perfect paper - surely it must happen sometime....

Comment: Since the paper has been accepted, is there something more you're looking for from a report?

Comment: @Lawrence Even reports recommending acceptance tend to have some suggestions for improvements, even if it as trivial as a typo.

Comment: @Anyon In the OP's case, though, the paper was actually accepted (not just recommended for acceptance) - the editor felt that it was good enough as-is. Since there were no typos or improvements needed, it's perhaps the scholarly interaction that the OP was looking for from a report - or perhaps it was something else.

Comment: @Lawrence Even in a case of no comments, I would expect a referee report stating this, so not having such a report indicates that there may have been some mistake, and clearing that up now may be easier than later on.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft - I've had a variety of papers over the years accepted as-is without referee reports. Materials/physics, not math, but still...

Comment: @SolarMike: A 60-page paper? Without so much as a typo? In theory, yes, it might happen. In practice... Nah.

Comment: @tomasz Not all reviewers are diligent enough to list every mistake. I'm sure we've all seen reviewers comments of less than a paragraph (usually on rejections/recommendations for revision, but still...)

Comment: @origimbo: Of course. I'm not saying that it's not plausible the referee did not *find* mistakes. I'm just questioning the possibility that there were no mistakes to be found.

Comment: Not all reviews list things like typos, esp if someone is not a native speaker. While an empty report with one sentence recommending to publication may not enough to the editor, I find it possible that the editor does not forward the opinion if they are just brief statements of positive opinon.

Answer (score 38):

Yes, asking the editor about this seems very reasonable, as not getting any sort of report from the reviewers sounds like an error.
(I have published one paper in J. Algebra, and we did get a reviewer report, just as one would expect).